# running location services while browsing the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, location

So I have two view controllers in my iphone project - one of them collects user location data and saves to a file continuously, and the other one does something else (doesnt really matter). I would like to keep the location updates running once the user flips to the other view controller since I am logging and saving to a file his location. How can I keep running the location updates and file savings while on other view controllers (even if I had more than 2 view controllers total)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of CLLocationManager and start monitoring for location changes (or significant location changes if that works for you). You can create this instance in your AppDelegate or some other class that is unrelated to the view controllers.

Comment: But if I want to avoid doing that in the AppDelegate - does it make sense to instantiate it twice? in two different view controllers?

Comment: If it fits within your design, then yes. It will not hurt to have two running. It will require that you turn it on and off in two places though.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I just run into - my location manager in the second view is not getting any updates. I turned off the first location manager in the first view controller at viewDidUnload, with stopUpdatingLocation, but nothing...is that the way to do that? thanks a bunch!

Comment: Did you start monitoring for location changes on you second CLLocationManager? You need to start monitoring for each manager that you want monitoring. Conversely you must stop monitoring for each one.